# How to throttle md-autocomplete calls to my back-end when typing into an input?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, md-autocomplete

I am using an angular `md-autocomplete` input on one of my web forms. I've got it all setup and it is working great.

As expected, whenever I type a new character into the autocomplete input a call to my back-end is made to get the autocomplete data. The problem is I don't want to make a back-end call every time a new character is input. I only want the back-end call to fire if it has been x seconds since the last time a back-end call was made.

Here's the function that gets called when a character is input:

```
function autocomplete(inputValue) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    portalState.apiPost(
        'api/cats/search',
        { 
            SearchType: 'all',
            SearchTerm: inputValue
        },
        function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(null);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

That's my working function before I try and put in any throttling logic. The main issue I have when I put in throttling logic is that I don't know what to return that will not cause angular to throw an error, for example:

```
function autocomplete(inputValue) {
    var isCool = false;

    if(isCool) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        portalState.apiPost(
            'api/cats/search',
            { 
                SearchType: 'all',
                SearchTerm: inputValue
            },
            function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(null);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
    else {
        //is there some sort of
        //empty promise I can return
        //so that angular won't
        //throw an error
    }
}
```

So what can I return if I don't want to make the back-end call? Or is there an easier way to throttle an angular `md-autocomplete` input?

Comment: You can set a number of characters before it start searching on your back-end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the documentation on Angular Material, you can set two things.

A number of character to start searching on your back end with `md-min-length`

Or Also an amount of time in miliseconds with `md-delay`

Please check here [md-autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)